# Scrape contents of dynamic pop-up window using R

Tags: r, popup, web-scraping, rvest

I'm stuck on this one after much searching....

I started with scraping the contents of a table from:

http://www.skatepress.com/skates-top-10000/artworks/

Which is easy:

```
data <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:100){
  print(paste("page", i, "of 100"))
  url <- paste("http://www.skatepress.com/skates-top-10000/artworks/", i, "/", sep = "")
  temp <- readHTMLTable(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, url, which = 1, encoding = "UTF-8")
   data <- rbind(data, temp)
} # end of scraping loop
```

However, I need to additionally scrape the detail that is contained in a pop-up box when you click on each name (and on the artwork title) in the list on the site.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass the breadcrumb (or artist-id or painting-id) through in order to make this happen. Since straight up using rvest to access the contents of the nodes doesn't work, I've tried the following:

I tried passing the painting id through in the url like this:

```
url <- ("http://www.skatepress.com/skates-top-10000/artworks/?painting_id=576")
site <- html(url)
```

But it still gives an empty result when scraping:

```
  node1 <- "bread-crumb > ul > li.activebc"
  site %>% html_nodes(node1) %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)

character(0)
```

I'm (clearly) not a scraping expert so any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated! I need a way to capture this additional information for each of the 10,000 items on the list...hence why I'm not interested in doing this manually!

Hoping this is an easy one and I'm just overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 3):

This will be a more efficient base scraper and you can get progress bars for free with the `pbapply` package:

```
library(xml2)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(pbapply)
library(jsonlite)

base_url <- "http://www.skatepress.com/skates-top-10000/artworks/%d/"

n <- 100
bind_rows(pblapply(1:n, function(i) {
  mutate(html_table(html_nodes(read_html(sprintf(base_url, i)), "table"))[[1]],
         `Sale Date`=as.Date(`Sale Date`, format="%m.%d.%Y"),
         `Premium Price USD`=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `Premium Price USD`)))
})) -> skatepress
```

I added trivial date & numeric conversions.

I belive your main issue is that the site requires a login to get the additional data. You should give that (i.e. logging in) a shot using `httr` and grab the `wordpress_logged_inXXXXXXX…` cookie from that endeavour. I just grabbed it from inspecting the session with Developer Tools in Chrome and that will also work for you (but it's worth the time to learn how to do it via `httr`).

You'll need to scrape two additional `<a …` tags from each table row. The one for "artist" looks like:

```
<a href="#" data-type="artist" data-id="pab_pica_1881">Pablo Picasso</a>
```

You can scrape the contents with:

```
POST("http://www.skatepress.com/wp-content/themes/skatepress/scripts/query_artist.php",
     set_cookies(wordpress_logged_in_XXX="userid%XXXXXreallylongvalueXXXXX…"),
     encode="form",
     body=list(id="pab_pica_1881"),
     verbose()) -> artist_response

fromJSON(content(artist_response, as="text"))
```

(The return value is too large to post here)

The one for "artwork" looks like:

```
<a href="#" data-type="artwork" data-id="576">Les femmes d′Alger (Version ′O′)</a>
```

and you can get that in similar fashion:

```
POST("http://www.skatepress.com/wp-content/themes/skatepress/scripts/query_artwork.php",
     set_cookies(wordpress_logged_in_XXX="userid%XXXXXreallylongvalueXXXXX…"),
     encode="form",
     body=list(id=576),
     verbose()) -> artwork_response

fromJSON(content(artwork_response, as="text"))
```

That's not huge but I won't clutter the response with it.

NOTE that you can also use `rvest`'s `html_session` to do the login (which will get you cookies for free) and then continue to use that session in the scraping (vs `read_html`) which will mean you don't have to do the `httr` `GET`/`PUT`.

You'll have to figure out how you want to incorporate that data into the data frame or associate it with it via various id's in the data frame (or some other strategy).

You can see it call those two php scripts via Developer Tools and it also shows the data it passes in. I'm also really shocked that site doesn't have any anti-scraping clauses in their ToS but they don't.